# Plugin for xml api response

Tags: java, android, xml, api

I am getting html response from server i want xml response from my webserver so Which plugin to use to get XML response from server. Can any one help me regarding this it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that having an xml from a webserver, file or whatever is the same for the Java XPath API.
So, you have to apply this following :

```
            //Partie connexion
        URL url = new URL(addressToConnect);
        HttpURLConnection connexion = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connexion.connect();
        InputSource geocoderResultInputSource;
        geocoderResultInputSource = new InputSource(connexion.getInputStream());
        
        //Partie XML/XPATH
        
        Document geocoderResultDocument = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(geocoderResultInputSource);
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        NodeList nodeListCodeResult = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//status", geocoderResultDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

etc...

[More examples here, from a project that I'm making](http://code.google.com/p/geocoder-library/source/browse/)

Hope it's helps ;)